# SSLException: SSL handshake abortedが発生する要因を知りたい

Tags: android

ListViewで写真一覧を作っており、写真はOkHttpというライブラリを用いてネットから取得するようにしています。

例えば、全50枚あるリストを勢い良くスクロールしている途中(序盤や中盤など)でタイトルに書いた例外が発生することがあります。
(ListViewが表示されてすぐスクロール開始したなら発生しない？)
キャンセル処理を行った時とその例外発生した時のImageViewのhashCode・読み込みURLを比較してみたところ、キャンセル処理を行ったかどうかにかかわらず発生するようです。
その例外は何が要因で発生するものなのでしょうか？

ちなみにOSはAndroid 4.4.2を使用しています。
その時の例外は以下の通りです。

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x648aa828: I/O error during system call, Bad file number
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)                                   
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)                   
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:195)                                   
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:148)                                
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)                                      
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)                         
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)                  
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)                               
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)                                            
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)                                        
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)                                                          
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)                                  
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)                                      
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)                                                            
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)                                                    
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)                                                
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
```

読み込みコードは以下の通りです。

```
    /**
     * URLから写真をロードしてセット.

     * 写真はViewに対して任意に設定したサイズでロードされる。
     *
     * @param photoUrl 写真取得に使用するURL
     */
    protected void loadPhoto(final String photoUrl) {
        if (getTag() != null) {
            ((Call) getTag()).cancel();
        }
        setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_animation);
        ((AnimationDrawable) getDrawable()).start();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(photoUrl)
                .get()
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        setTag(call);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            /**
             * リクエストキャンセル・接続の問題・タイムアウトのために実行できなった場合
             *
             * @param call
             * @param e エラー内容
             */
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                setTag(null); //通信終了
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (e instanceof SocketException) {
                    //キャンセル要求による反応は何もしない
                    return;
                }
                //それ以外は接続切れ扱い
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setImageResource(R.drawable.error);

                    }
                });
                EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent.connectionError(""));
            }

            /**
             * 応答が正常に返された場合
             * エラーステータスも含む
             *
             * @param call
             * @param response リクエストの結果
             */
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                setTag(null);
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(UserEvent.connectionError(String.valueOf(response.code())));
                    return;
                }
                InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });
                response.body().close();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSLの通信が途中で切断されているように見受けられます。

勢い良くスクロールしている途中に発生するということなので、短時間で多数のアクセスになり、取得先のサーバから切断された可能性があります。(おそらくTCPレベルで切断されているので、tcpdump などで確かめてみると良いかもしれません。)

Comment: そういう要因であの例外が発生しているのですね。非root化の実機でtPacketCaptureでパケットをキャプチャしたものやGenymotionでそのコマンドを使ってキャプチャしたものをCocoaPacketAnalyzerに読み込ませてみたのですが、パケット解析をした経験がないのでよくわかりませんでした。とりあえず要因を知れてスッキリしました。ありがとうございました。